# Convert Byte Array to string ascii encoding

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte, ascii

I'm converting a byte array to a string using ASCii encoding but the values ​​are not correct, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can you help me?

```
byte [] crouzet = new byte[11];

    crouzet[0]= (0x3A);
    crouzet[1]= (0x04);
    crouzet[2]= (0x10);
    crouzet[3]= (0x00);
    crouzet[4]= (0x00);
    crouzet[5]= (byte) 0xff;
    crouzet[6]= (0x00);
    crouzet[7]= (0x02);
    crouzet[8]= (0x00);
    crouzet[9]= (0x01);

    byte checksum = (byte) (0xff -((crouzet[1])+crouzet[2]+crouzet[3]+crouzet[4]+crouzet[5]+crouzet[6]+crouzet[7]+crouzet[8]+crouzet[9]) +0x01);

    crouzet[10] = checksum;
    String string = new String(crouzet, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

    
    Log.d("TAG", "Checksum" + Arrays.toString(crouzet));
    Log.d("TAG", "Checksum" + string);
```

in my logcat this result :

[image]

Comment: You're printing a byte array and a String literal value. Why do you expect them to be the same? I would imagine Arrays.toString is likely using the default charset which is likely UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. What is the expected output?

Comment: The ASCII encoding only supports byte values 0-127 (0x00 - 0x7F in hex), the rest get converted into the `<?>` replacement character. What output did you expect? If you show a sample of the expected output maybe we can suggest a way to obtain it.

Comment: If you're looking to compare the String and the byte array you might want to do the following; `Arrays.toString(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))`

Comment: ASCII codes `0x00` and `0x01` and `0x02` are non-printable characters. How do you expect them to appear?

Comment: @Joni I don't expect them to be the same just print them out to view, the value Arrays.toString is correct is what I expected but the string value ASCii I expected Receive something like :04100000FF00020001EA

Comment: So something like `new BigInteger(crouzet).toString(16)`? It yields `3a04100000ff00020001ea`. Hard to tailor to more exact requirements, I admit.